# Selecting the lastest record from a resultset (mysql, php)

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have written this code to get some info from my database.

```
       "SELECT 
        c.from AS user_id, 
        c.time AS time,
        u.user_firstname AS user_firstname, 
        u.user_lastname AS user_lastname, 
        u.user_profile_picture AS user_profile_picture       
        FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.from WHERE c.to = :id1 
        UNION SELECT 
        c.to  AS user_id,    
        c.time AS time,       
        u2.user_firstname AS user_firstname, 
        u2.user_lastname AS user_lastname, 
        u2.user_profile_picture AS user_profile_picture
        FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id = c.to WHERE c.from= :id2 
        ORDER BY time DESC"
```

it's work great except one thing. Since this is a inbox script there are many message from same user. but i only need to check if there is a message from this user or not.

```
array (size=28)
0 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 6
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 19:53:58' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'john' (length=4)
  'user_lastname' => string 'doe' (length=3)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '6_user_profile.jpg' (length=19)
1 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 2
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 16:59:50' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'james' (length=5)
  'user_lastname' => string 'bond' (length=4)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '2_user_profile.jpg' (length=19)
2 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 6
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 02:15:44' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'john' (length=4)
  'user_lastname' => string 'doe' (length=3)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '6_user_profile.jpg' (length=19)
3 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 6
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 02:13:21' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'john' (length=4)
  'user_lastname' => string 'doe' (length=3)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '6_user_profile.jpg'(length=19)
4 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 2
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 01:58:59' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'james' (length=5)
  'user_lastname' => string 'bond' (length=4)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '2_user_profile.jpg'(length=19)
```

as you can see in the var_dump there are 3 john doe and 2 james bond. but I need only the last ones according to the time. 
so in this case john doe from 19:53:58, and james bond from  16:59:50. Like this:

```
array (size=2)
0 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 6
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 19:53:58' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'john' (length=4)
  'user_lastname' => string 'doe' (length=3)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '6_user_profile.jpg' (length=19)
1 => 
array (size=5)
  'user_id' => int 2
  'time' => string '2014-05-13 16:59:50' (length=19)
  'user_firstname' => string 'james' (length=5)
  'user_lastname' => string 'bond' (length=4)
  'user_profile_picture' => string '2_user_profile.jpg' (length=19)
```

and if there are some other users i want to get their last records too.
how can i do this? is this possible with only one query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one I tested.

```
 "SELECT *
    FROM (SELECT 
    c.from AS user_id, 
    c.time AS time,
    u.user_firstname AS user_firstname, 
    u.user_lastname AS user_lastname, 
    u.user_profile_picture AS user_profile_picture       
    FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.from WHERE c.to = :id1 
    UNION
  SELECT 
    c.to  AS user_id,    
    c.time AS time,       
    u2.user_firstname AS user_firstname, 
    u2.user_lastname AS user_lastname, 
    u2.user_profile_picture AS user_profile_picture
    FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id = c.to WHERE c.from= :id2 
) AS bynames
  GROUP BY user_id ORDER BY time ASC"
```

Comment: yes thats it thank you very much

Comment: I don't think this does what you want. It groups by user first, selecting random sets of data for each user. Then it sorts the per-user information by time.

Comment: @Barmar i think Lennart's answer is the best

Answer (score 1):

Put the union in a subquery, order it in the main query, and limit that to the most recent row.

```
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT 
        c.from AS user_id, 
        c.time AS time,
        u.user_firstname AS user_firstname, 
        u.user_lastname AS user_lastname, 
        u.user_profile_picture AS user_profile_picture       
        FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.from WHERE c.to = :id1 
        UNION
      SELECT 
        c.to  AS user_id,    
        c.time AS time,       
        u2.user_firstname AS user_firstname, 
        u2.user_lastname AS user_lastname, 
        u2.user_profile_picture AS user_profile_picture
        FROM chat c INNER JOIN users u2 ON u2.user_id = c.to WHERE c.from= :id2 
    )
ORDER BY time DESC
LIMIT 1
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but i want to choose john doe from 19:53:58, and james bond from 16:59:50 and if there are other records, their last records too. in your script i only choose the last one which is only  john doe from 19:53:58

Comment: So you want the latest message from each unique user?

Comment: @Alex.Ritna yes that's correct. think like that: On facebook you have an inbox. Your friends name are there only one time. Even if you start another conversation with them they wont show up twice. And if you click their name you will see the full conversation.

Comment: Instead of the `LIMIT 1` try `GROUP BY user_id`. This should provide you with the latest on a per user basis.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1313120/retrieving-the-last-record-in-each-group for how to select the latest record in each group.

Answer (score 0):

Untested

`SELECT c.user_id
      , MAX(c.time)
      , u.user_firstname
      , u.user_lastname
      , u.user_profile_picture
 FROM (
     SELECT from AS user_id
          , time
     FROM chat
     WHERE to = :id1
     UNION 
     SELECT to AS user_id
          , time
     FROM chat
     WHERE from = :id2
 ) as c
 JOIN users u 
    ON u.user_id = c.user_id
 GROUP BY c.user_id
     , u.user_firstname
     , u.user_lastname
     , u.user_profile_picture`

Comment: @Lenmart thank you for your answer but i reveived many error

Comment: Would you mind sharing the errors with us?

Comment: @lenmart sure> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ' in C:\wamp\www\Onuruna\httpdocs\includes\message.php on line 82 (which is the last line)

Comment: Can you post create table statements for users and chat?

Comment: sorry but there is no create table statements. what do you want to learn?

Comment: I need to create the tables in order to investigate the error

Comment: I tested it on 5.5.37-MariaDB. It complained on from so I renamed that column to from_ and then it worked. MariaDB [test]> SELECT c.user_id , MAX(c.time) , u.user_firstname , u.user_lastname , u.user_profile_picture FROM ( SELECT from_ AS user_id , time FROM chat WHERE to_ = 1 UNION SELECT to_ AS user_id , time FROM chat WHERE from_ = 1 ) as c JOIN users u ON u.user_id = c.user_id GROUP BY c.user_id , u.user_firstname , u.user_lastname , u.user_profile_picture;
Empty set (0.01 sec)